# How do I configure jetty-maven-plugin to log oejs, oejsh, oejsh packages

Tags: plugins, maven, logging, jetty

I am trying to configure jetty-maven-plugin 8.0.3.v20111011.
I am running deploy war goal. with demon = true.

I am not able to see logs from oejs, oejsh, oejsh packages.

For getting logs I tried 2 ways.

1> setting log4j for plugin
2> setting stdOut and StdErr... however I am still not able to get the logs

following is my POM, log4j.properties and jetty-logging.xml

```
    <plugin>  
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>  
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>8.0.3.v20111011</version>  
        <configuration>  
            <systemProperties>                          
                <systemProperty>  
                    <name>org.apache.commons.logging.Log</name>  
                    <value>org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger</value>  
                </systemProperty>  
                <systemProperty>  
                    <name>slf4j</name>  
                    <value>false</value>  
                </systemProperty>  
                <systemProperty>  
                    <name>log4j.configuration</name>  
                    <value>file:///${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/log4j.properties</value>  
                </systemProperty>  
                <systemProperty>  
                    <name>jetty.logs</name>  
                    <value>.</value>  
                </systemProperty>  
            </systemProperties>  
            <war>${deploy.war}</war>  
            <webApp>  
                <contextPath>${server.basePath}</contextPath>  
            </webApp>  
            <connectors>  
                <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">  
                    <port>${server.run.port}</port>  
                </connector>  
            </connectors>  
            <stopPort>${server.stop.port}</stopPort>  
            <stopKey>hola</stopKey>  
            <jettyConfig>th-integration/src/test/resources/jetty-logging.xml</jettyConfig>  
        </configuration>  
        <executions>  
            <execution>  
                <id>start-jetty</id>  
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>  
                <goals>  
                    <goal>deploy-war</goal>  
                </goals>  
                <configuration>  
                    <daemon>true</daemon>  
                    <reload>manual</reload>  
                </configuration>  
            </execution>  
            <execution>  
                <id>stop-jetty</id>  
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>  
                <goals>  
                    <goal>stop</goal>  
                </goals>  
            </execution>  
        </executions>                  
    </plugin>  

    log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, server  
    log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender  
    log4j.appender.server.File=jetty_log4j.log  
    log4j.appender.server.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
    log4j.appender.server.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n  
    log4j.logger.org.mortbay.log=DEBUG  
    log4j.logger.oejsh.ContextHandler=DEBUG  
    log4j.logger.oejd.DeploymentManager=DEBUG  
    log4j.logger.oejs.ServletHandler=DEBUG  
    log4j.logger.oejs.AbstractConnector=DEBUG  

<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">  
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">  
    <!--Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer"-->  
    <New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">  
        <Arg>  
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">  
                <Arg>yyyy_mm_dd.jetty_console.log</Arg>  
                <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>  
                <Arg type="int">90</Arg>  
                <Arg>  
                    <Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone">  
                        <Arg>GMT</Arg>  
                    </Call>  
                </Arg>  
                <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>  
            </New>  
        </Arg>  
    </New>    
    <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info">  
        <Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to  
            <Ref id="ServerLogName"/>  
        </Arg>  
    </Call>  
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr">  
        <Arg>  
            <Ref id="ServerLog"/>  
        </Arg>  
    </Call>  
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut">  
        <Arg>  
            <Ref id="ServerLog"/>  
        </Arg>  
    </Call>  
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL to DEBUG

On the commandline you just use -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG so I think your issue is that you shouldn't be shortening those package names in your configuration to oejs, we do that on output just to save some space, the actual levels are for the actual package names.